# Code executes in chrome perfectly but it executes up to the "send sms only " when I run on Mozilla

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

```
package vaishu;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Anusha {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\ishu\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver r=new FirefoxDriver();
        r.get("http://site24.way2sms.com/content/index.html?");
        r.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("9494536902");
        r.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("spandana536");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        r.findElement(By.id("loginBTN")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        r.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logemail']/following-sibling::*[2]")).click();
        r.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Send Free SMS']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
            r.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sendSMS']/child::*")).click();
            r.switchTo().frame("frame");
        r.findElement(By.name("mobile")).sendKeys("7000214176");
        r.findElement(By.id("message")).sendKeys("hi");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        r.findElement(By.id("Send")).click();


    }


}
```

Comment: Please show us the error message you're seeing when you try to run in Mozilla.  This will be critical for us to help you most effectively.

Comment: actually no error is coming, without error it is executing.

Comment: try to execute in your lap please

Comment: What is your Selenium, geckodriver & Mozilla Firefox version? Try to use Selenium 3.4.0 with geckodriver v.0.16.1 along with Mozilla Firefox 53.0 and update me what you observe.

Comment: @dev using same versions as you said above. but unable to get , showing error as unable to findelement. only in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine.

A few points:

1. Avoid using `Thread.sleep(5000);` in your code, instead use `ImplicitlyWait` or `ExplicitWait`
2. While you switchover to a frame, induce some `wait` for the elements on the frame to render.
3. Rendering of elements present in the HTML DOM is done differently by different browsers (e.g. Chrome, Mozilla, IE, Safari, Edge, Opera), so you have induce proper `wait`
4. Try to provide name of the instances which is closer, e.g instead of `WebDriver r` you can `WebDriver driver`
5. Here is the working code on Mozilla Firefox 53.0

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\ishu\\geckodriver.exe"); 

   WebDriver r=new FirefoxDriver();

   r.get("http://site24.way2sms.com/content/index.html?");
   r.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("9494536902");
   r.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("spandana536");
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   r.findElement(By.id("loginBTN")).click();
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   r.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logemail']/following-sibling::*[2]")).click();
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   r.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Send Free SMS']")).click();
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   r.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sendSMS']/child::*")).click();
   r.switchTo().frame("frame");
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   r.findElement(By.name("mobile")).sendKeys("7000214176");
   r.findElement(By.id("message")).sendKeys("hi");
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   r.findElement(By.id("Send")).click();
   ```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: what is the difference between our codes

Comment: please tell me the answer to the error , element is not visible..(element is not finding is different from that i think). please anyone